# FOR loop spaces and handling

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a batch script that lists all services,takes the BINARY_PATH,  removes any lines that contain c"\windows" and provides a list of BINARY_PATHS.

The idea is to then pass that list into ICACLS to determine the permissions set on each of those executables.

The problem I have is that some BINARY_PATHS contain leading and trailing ". 
So I have had to account for this by adding the delims=" to my for /f statement.

**Below is the batch file that outputs to ECHO**

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%n in ('sc query state^= all ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME') do (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%r in (
    'sc qc "%%~n" ^| findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME'
  ) do (
    for /f tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^" %%x in ('echo %%~s^| findstr /V /I "c:\windows\system32"') do (
         echo "%%~x%%~y" 
        )
  )
)
```

**The ECHO output is as following - a nice clean list it would seem apart from the leading space**

```
" C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_state.exe"
" C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsvw.exe"
" C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\WPF\PresentationFontCache.exe"
" C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\infoc
ard.exe"
" C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMSvc
Host.exe"
" C:\Program Files\Photodex\ProShow Producer\ScsiAccess.exe"
" C:\Windows\servicing\TrustedInstaller.exe"
" C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\vmtoolsd.exe"
```

When I try and pass the output to icacls without the leading and trailing ",  it breaks down because there are spaces in some of the PATHs.

**ICACLS batch file:**

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%n in ('sc query state^= all ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME') do (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%r in (
    'sc qc "%%~n" ^| findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME'
  ) do (
    for /f tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^" %%x in ('echo %%~s ^| findstr /V /I "c:\windows\system32"') do (
         icacls %%~x%%~y 
        )
  )
)
```

**Some output from ICACLS batch:**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\WPF\PresentationFontCache.exe NT SERVICE
\TrustedInstaller:(F)
                                                                      BUILTIN\Ad
ministrators:(RX)
                                                                      NT AUTHORI
TY\SYSTEM:(RX)
                                                                      BUILTIN\Us
ers:(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
Invalid parameter "Communication"
Invalid parameter "Communication"
Invalid parameter "Files\Photodex\ProShow"
C:\Windows\servicing\TrustedInstaller.exe NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
                                          BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)
                                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)
                                          BUILTIN\Users:(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
Invalid parameter "Files\VMware\VMware"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The outer-most `for /f` loop uses variable `%%n`, the inner-most one also uses variable `%%n` implicitly due to `%%m` and the `tokens=1-2` option; although it works, I recommend to use non-overlapping variables for the inner-most loop (e. g., `%%x`, and so also `%%y`). To remove leading and trailing `""`, you do not need the `delims^=^"` option; just state `for /f "delims=" %%x in ('echo %%~s') do echo %%~x` (the `~` modifier removes the quotes)...

Comment: The problem is more the leading and trailing spaces than the "".

Comment: You mean leading/trailing white-spaces *outside* of the surrounding double-quotes? As far as I can see, the `echo %%~s ^| findstr ...` portion can lead to a *trailing* space, which can be avoided by removing the space before the (escaped) pipe, like `echo %%~s^| findstr ...`; I cannot see a source for *leading* spaces, but if there are some, you can remove them by `for /F "tokens=*" %%l in (...) do echo %%l` (remember the default delimiters _space_ and _tab_)...

Comment: thanks, sorry I might not explained correctly. If you look at the code, I have to add " " around the output to make it work with icacls, at which point there is a leading space " c:\path\path\executable"

Comment: Ah, I see! the middle `for /f` loop is the source of the leading space; to avoid that, change it to this: `for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%r`; I simply exchanged `tokens` and `delims` options and defined a *space* as the last delimiter (the space is only taken as delimiter if it is the very last character in the option string); this avoids the leading space and works since the first token does not contain spaces on its own...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right to enclose paths in between quotation marks in order to avoid trouble with white-spaces.
But instead of removing and leading and trailing spaces which are also contained within the `""`, I would try to not produce them rather than to eliminate them later.

---

The leading space comes from the middle `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%r in ('sc qc "%%~n" ^| findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME') do ( ... )
```

The filtered `sc qc` command produces output lines like:

> ```
>         BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
>         BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\iPod\bin\iPodService.exe"
> ```

With your `"delims=: tokens=1*"` option, the part after the delimiter (`:`) holds a leading space.
To overcome this, add the space as another delimiter, but make sure it is the very last character in the option string: `"tokens=1* delims=: "`.

---

The trailing space comes from the piped `echo` command line parsed by the inner `for /f` loop:

```
for /f tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^" %%x in ('echo %%~s ^| findstr /V /I "c:\windows\system32"') do ( ... )
```

The space between `echo %%~s` and `^|` is also included in the output. Therefore simply remove it.
It is not necessary to define the option string `tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^"`, because the `for /f` loop should not receive any quotation marks to parse anyway (due to the `~` modifier in `%%~s`), so `"delims="` is enough. Hence use `%%~x` in the loop body only.
Furthermore, I suggest to write `echo(%%~s` instead of `echo %%~s` in order to avoid `ECHO is on/off.` messages if `%%~s` is empty (although this should never happen).

---

Another problem is that service names retrieved by `sc query state= all` may contain white-spaces as well; for example:

> ```
> SERVICE_NAME: iPod Service
> ```

So for the outer `for /f` loop, the `"tokens=2"` option is not optimal; in the above example, only `iPod` would be returned. Therefore correct it to `"tokens=1*"` and ignore the first token.

---

Since literal strings are searched only, I replaced the `findstr` instances by `find`, except the last one, because `find` supports a single search string only.
I added another search string to the remaining `findstr` instance in order to cover also 64-bit Windows systems where a directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` also exists, which I assume you want to filter out too.

---

Here is the fixed code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%m in ('sc query state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%r in ('sc qc "%%~n" ^| find "BINARY_PATH_NAME"') do (
        for /f "delims=" %%x in ('echo(%%~s^| findstr /L /V /I /C:"%SystemRoot%\System32" /C:"%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64"') do (
            ECHO icacls "%%~x"
        )
    )
)
```

Remove the upper-case `ECHO` after successful testing in order to execute the `icacls` command line.